# Are the types that show monads are more powerful than continuations revealing something of fundamental importance?

Tags: type-theory, type-systems, monad, continuations

In 1992 in the paper *[Imperative Functional Programming](http://cse.iitk.ac.in/users/karkare/courses/2010/cs653/Papers/imperative.pdf)*, Simon Peyton Jones and Philip Wadler write:

> So monads are more powerful than continuations, but only because of the types! It is not clear whether this is only an artifact of the Hindley-Milner type system, or whether the types are revealing a difference of fundamental importance (our own intuition it's the latter -- but it's only an intuition.)

There seems to be a lack of evidence for the Hindley-Milner side of the question. (Perhaps there is an interesting paper in this as well).

My question is: **Are the types that show monads are more powerful than continuations revealing something of fundamental importance?** (ie are there some papers that have addressed this since 1992).